# problems with sudo apt-get update

Tags: raspbian, wireless, apt, wireless-adapter

I just received my new pi3 today and was setting it up. I managed to get raspbian working but now when I try to run the command sudo apt-get update or sudo apt-get upgrade I get an error saying

```
Unable to connect to archive.rasberrypi.org:http: [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:13:0:6:80]
```

Now, I tried adding the google DNS ip to the resolv.conf file but it didnt fix the problem and the worst part is that I have no access to an ethernet connection (student who lives in a dorm room), so I can only use the wifi adapter. So far I have no problem browsing the internet it's just when I try to run the commands sudo apt-get update or sudo apt-get upgrade.

Is there any way to solve this problem? This is my first time using linux and so far I am quite lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
j
[image: ust added a screenshot of a ping to archive.raspberrypi.org]

[image: this is the updated one]

Comment: Open a terminal and type `ping archive.raspberrypi.org`, and update your post with the output of that command. This will narrow it down a bit.

Comment: I just uploaded the screenshot, thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Now try `sudo apt-get clean`, and after it's done try `sudo apt-get update` again, this might clear it up.

Comment: Wait, hold on. Your Pi3 is trying to hit Wheezy repos. Which version of Raspbian did you install?

Comment: well I did add some extra repositories, maybe its because of that, Ill remove them and try again

Comment: just updated it and tried again. Still no success.

Comment: For what it is worth, it is not uncommon to get "Unable to connect to archive". This appears to be an internet problem. It usually goes away (in a few minutes, sometimes next day).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Pi3 has:

- internet access
- can resolve hostnames
- can ping the servers
- a newly installed OS

The most likely issue is that the SD card got corrupted. Sometimes it happens during the creation of the SD card, sometimes it's an improper shutdown.

Make a new SD card, and make sure you use the software shutdown process before pulling the plug on your Pi.

Comment: got it, by making a new SD card you refer to formatting it and unzipping the NOOBS_V2_1_0 file on it, right?

Comment: Yup. Or if you feel up to it, download Raspbian directly instead of going through NOOBS. :)

Comment: reinstalling raspbian fixed my problem, thanks a lot!